# Android RecyclerView Adapter notifyItemChanged doesn't call onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm trying to load first movie data from firestore and then pass it to recycler view while displaying a loading gif, then download the image and now pass update recycler view adapter to show the movie pic.

My problem is until the point before I call `notifyItemChanged(x)` the movieBitmap which i want to pass is defined, but something seems to happen in the process of passing it to the adapter.
The `onBindViewHolder` function isn't even called, I don't know whhy

Here's my Loading from Storage Code:

```
private fun loadRestMoviesFromStorage() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        for (restMoviePosition in 1..movies[currentPosition - 1].restMoviesCount!!) {
            val file: File =
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { File.createTempFile("restMovieName1", "jpg") }
            var originalBitMap: Bitmap

            restMoviesStorageReference
                .child("restMovies/${restMovie.originalMovieName} Rest$restMoviePosition")
                .getFile(file)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        originalBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)

                        when (restMoviePosition) {
                            1 -> restMoviePics[0] = originalBitMap
                            2 -> restMoviePics[1] = originalBitMap
                            3 -> restMoviePics[2] = originalBitMap
                            4 -> restMoviePics[3] = originalBitMap
                            5 -> restMoviePics[4] = originalBitMap
                            6 -> restMoviePics[5] = originalBitMap
                            7 -> restMoviePics[6] = originalBitMap
                            8 -> restMoviePics[7] = originalBitMap
                            9 -> restMoviePics[8] = originalBitMap
                        }


                        updateRestMovies(restMoviePosition)
                    } else {
                        handleLoadingErrors("loadRestMoviesFromStorage",
                            it.exception?.message.toString())
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

My Initial Defining Recycler View Adapter Code:

```
private fun openRestMoviesDialog() {
    val adapter =
        movies[currentPosition - 1].restMoviesCount?.let { MovieSeriesAdapter(restMovie, it,
            restMoviePics) }

    lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
        val restDialogTrailerBinding = SeriesMoviesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        if (seriesTextClicked) {
            restMovieLoadingDialog.setContentView(restDialogTrailerBinding.root)
            restDialogTrailerBinding.rvSeriesMovies.adapter = adapter
            restDialogTrailerBinding.rvSeriesMovies.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        }
    }
}
```

My Update Function Code:

```
private fun updateRestMovies(movieNumber: Int) {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
        val restDialogTrailerBinding = SeriesMoviesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        Log.e("a7a", "${restMoviePics[0]}")
        restDialogTrailerBinding.rvSeriesMovies.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(movieNumber + 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: val restDialogTrailerBinding = SeriesMoviesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) not a correct way to get reference, use binding object with is created in fragment or activity

Comment: The recycler view is in a custom dialog

Comment: Then save the binding object reference, the way are you doing you are creating new binding object

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: OnBindViewHolder doesn't get called again after I call the updateRestMovies function

Comment: I've made the restMoviesDialogBinding a top levle variable, and used it in both the `openRestMovieDialog` and the `updateRestMovies`function, but it also didn't work